# "Slow" start diesel

Tags: diesel, winter, vacuum

Starting at low temperatures and sitting all night outside at below 5°C my car starts "slow". Like you can see in the video below, it will start with no problem but the engine hangs at 700rpm for a few seconds and only then it will start up the electricity (in the cabin and also main lights) and revs a little harder (which should be normal from the begining).
There are no DTCs, glow plugs were changed last year, car starts normally when warm, battery was changed last year, fuel filter 10.000km ago with OEM, EGR and throttle body cleaned. I have no slightest clue what could be wrong.

There's another problem when engine is warm (if that issue is somehow connected to this one). There's pretty noticeable rough idle when stopped and also RPMs fluctuate when coming to a stop. Interesting here is that rough idle at stop dissapears when I turn ON the AC or steer the wheels (put a load on the engine).

Car: Volvo s80 w/ 360.000km (220.000 miles)

Model Year: 2009

Engine code: D5244T5

Transmission: Manual M66

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIP6n9P7DSA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSIj2-B81Ts

EDIT:

- I've also did a injector delivery volume test with Volvo VIDA software, which showed no major differences between all five injectors.
- The other day I've open the oil fill cap and discovered the popping sound, so I think I've got a vacuum leak. This is regarding the warm engine problem (rough idle)

EDIT #2:

- I managed to eliminate roughness in engine at idle when hot by treating the engine with diesel additive (2 liters of it - one liter per 1/8 of tank). Engine now idles as smooth as ever.
- Still can't figure out that cold start problem, if anyone has any idea? Car still has no DTC codes and drives like a charm. Currently at 370.000 km.

Comment: My car is outside with low temperatures ( like -8 or -11 deg C) and I put a little (400W) heater under the bonnet. Comes on with a timer for 2 hours from 5AM and then it starts like a summer day. ***So** much less stress on all the components.

Comment: Yeah OK, but I'd really like to come to the bottom of this. What is actually cousing this. Had a s60 2004 D5 with 550.000km and it started at -18°C like it wasn't nothing, so that's what's bugging me :D

Comment: Have you serviced the injectors? or had them tested?

Comment: I had them tested in Volvo VIDA software and they show no problems at all.

Comment: Yesterday I've open the oil fill cap and discovered the popping sound, so I think I've got a vacuum leak. This is regarding the warm engine problem (rough idle), but I don't think a vacuum leak has anything to do with the cold start problem?

Comment: So does this vida software test the spray pattern, preesure and delivery volume?

Comment: I did a delivery volume test. It showed roughly the same amount for all five injectors

Comment: Add this detailed information to your question - saves all this to and fro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I want to clarify some things as I've resolved these problems.

**Regarding the cold start problem**

Old/lazy starter motor was the issue. I've replaced it with the aftermarket Bosch one and when at it I've also replaced the battery. Car now starts more lively and with better sound.

**Regarding the rough idle**

I drove 10.000 km since the last time I've put that Antigrippante 25 additive in the tank and engine is still running smooth, without any roughness in cold or hot conditions. I also want to point out that the injector fuel return pipes had a lot of rusty particles in it, meaning that there's water in our country's diesel, so I guess I'll add that additive at least once a year, as a preventive.